# Forward converter input current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm trying to calculate the Forward converter's efficiency. For that I calculate the losses, trying to include as much factors as possible. To calculate the loss on the input capacitor's ESR, I have to calculate the RMS current in the capacitor. For that I have to know the input current of the converter, which i suppose to be constant (so all the ripple currents are supplied by the input capacitor, which should be the ideal case). The easy way would be calculating the input current from the input voltage, the output power and the efficiency, but the problem is, that it would make it an implicit equation system, because for calculating the efficiency I already have to use the efficiency in the calculations.

My other idea is calculating the capacitor's amp-second balance. With that, I get \$I_{in}=I_{out}n_sD + \frac{I_{m}}{2}D(1-n_r)\$ , where \$n_s\$ is the primary to secondary turns ratio, \$I_{m}\$ is the peak magnetizing current and \$n_r \$ is the primary to reset winding turns ratio.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

With calculations like that you can get close, but usually there are too many parasitic features that need to be taken into account. If you want to know the efficiency for sure, you have to measure it.

Just measure input and output currents and voltages. You efficiency is η = (U_out * I_out) / (U_in * I_in)

You have to measure it with different loads because efficiency changes depending on the load.

Edit:
If you're just designing the converter, use a simulator to calculate the efficiency.

Comment: Of course measurement is above everything. I'm just trying to model it close enough to reality.

Comment: Ok, then I can really recommend using a simulator. It seems to me like a pointless exercise trying to calculate it manually.